# Without swiftmailer how to send mail in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php at line 496

Error:

> PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>   syntax error, unexpected '?'

PHP version 5.5.14
I'm unable to send mail in laravel.
When i send mail then above error occurs.
I'm unable to change version of PHP because my another script running on this PHP version.
Please help me

Comment: Can you post the code for which its saying Syntax error ?

Comment: What is your laravel version ?

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.5.40 & PHP version 7.0.10 & swiftmailer version 6.0.2

Comment: Error:
Swift_TransportException {#492 ▼
  #message: "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 2 possible authenticators"
  #code: 0
  #file: ../vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php"

Comment: laravel >> config >> mail.php file
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => '587',
'from' => [
        'address' => 'username@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'name',
    ],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
'password' => '*******',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unexpected ?` is related to the [`null coalescing operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), introduced in php 7.

Several directions you could take:

- upgrade the php version, which in your case is not possible.
- use [php's built in mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).
- downgrade swiftmailer to a version prior to php 7, e.g. `v5.4.9` (e.g. with `composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer:v5.4.9`)

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.5.40 & PHP version 7.0.10 & swiftmailer version 6.0.2

Comment: Error: Swift_TransportException {#492 ▼ #message: "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 2 possible authenticators" #code: 0 #file: ../vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php"

Comment: Thanks. Problem is fixed.
I use a php's built in mail function.